# How to find admin user of pluggable database in Oracle 12c up

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, users

I'm creating a script and I need to know what is the admin user of pluggable database. I don't find nothing about it in documentation.

Other question is, what happen if I drop a admin user of the pluggable database?  is there some problem?

Answer (score 2):

[CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-PLUGGABLE-DATABASE.html)

> **ADMIN USER**
>
> Use this clause to create an administrative user who can be granted
>   the privileges required to perform administrative tasks on the PDB.
>   For admin_user_name, specify name of the user to be created. Use the
>   IDENTIFIED BY clause to specify the password for admin_user_name.
>   Oracle Database creates a local user in the PDB and grants the PDB_DBA
>   local role to that user.

The admin user is just a local user with the PDB_DBA role.
Example:

```
SQL> CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE mypdb ADMIN USER balazs IDENTIFIED BY Oracle123 FILE_NAME_CONVERT=('pdbseed','mypdb');

Pluggable database created.

SQL> alter pluggable database mypdb open;

Pluggable database altered.

SQL> select grantee from cdb_role_privs where con_id = (select con_id from cdb_pdbs where pdb_name = 'MYPDB') and granted_role = 'PDB_DBA';

GRANTEE
--------------------
BALAZS
SYS
```